# grep all words with specified length, without letter x

Tags: grep, regular-expression

So I am stuck here:

`grep -E '^....c...c...$'` shows all words with the expr I need. Now from this words I only need the ones that don't have a `x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a second grep:

```
grep -E '^....c...c...$' | grep -v x
```

Or [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
grep -E '^[^x][^x][^x][^x]c[^x][^x][^x]c[^x][^x][^x]$'
```

Comment: ok that is the answer